# How to make a buffer between rows using start time and end time?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to print out free spaces as a buffer zone between each row in a table. Is there a way for me to do this within the django template?
This is the current code I have.

```
            <table id="upcomingtable" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Course</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Professor</th>
                    <th>Start</th>
                    <th>End</th>
                </tr>
            {% for next in upcoming %}
                <tr> 
                    <td>{{ next.course }}</td>
                    <td>{{ next.title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ next.prof }}</td>
                    <td>{{ next.stime }}</td>
                    <td>{{ next.etime }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td></tr> <!--Buffer here-->
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

This is my current upcoming query:

```
upcoming = Class.objects.filter(building__exact=b, floor__exact=f, room__exact=r, days__icontains=dayletter(day), etime__gt=datetime.datetime.now().time()).distinct().order_by('stime')
```

Basically I want to take the endtime (etime) and find the difference between it with the next start time that is iterated with the next start time and make a buffer in between these rows.
For example the end time now is 3:00pm and the next start time is 3:15pm I want to make a buffer of rows before it prints out the actual row.

```
Ex.
    3:00    info info info
    blank
    blank
    blank
    3:15    info info info
```

for looping within views.py

```
 for i, item in enumerate(range(len(upcoming)-1)):
    s1 = upcoming[i].etime
    s2 = upcoming[i+1].stime

    d2 = s2.hour*60 + s2.minute
    d1 = s1.hour*60 + s1.minute 

    d = d2 - d1

    if (d>0):
        upcoming[i].span = d/5
```

Thanks guys, I appreciate all your help!

Comment: in view you can create bogus data into `upcoming`. If you detect this data do a `<td cellspan="5">`.

Comment: my upcoming is actually an sql query that is already filtering many rows of data.

Comment: I just posted up my query for upcoming. How do I make the bogus data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the number of blank rows depends on the time difference between records, right? If so, you could try something like this:

```
upcoming = list(upcoming)
for i, item in enumerate(upcoming[:-1]):
    item.span = range(1, upcoming[i+1].sdate - item.edate)   #actually, get the time difference in minutes and divide by some coefficient - how many minutes should pass for the new blank row to be inserted
```

And then in template:

```
{% for row in next.span %}
    <tr><td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yea thats what I'm aiming for. But, I'm kinda confused with your for loop. how does that translate into my context?

Comment: There are two for loops, I'm not sure which one you mean. The Python one generates the span attribute for each item. This attribute is an array, which has the same length as the number of blank rows you need to insert after each line. Then in the template, where you commented "<!--Buffer here-->", you insert this second for loop, which inserts blank rows as many times as the length of span attribute is.

Comment: Where exactly does that happen? Are you sure you haven't missed anything? Because if it looks like the loop you added in the question body, it's not right.

Comment: I think I did it a different way. Thanks for your help!!